# PostGIS Select Union of Polygons

Tags: geometry, postgis-2.0, union

I have a Postgres 8.4 PostGIS 2.0 enabled database and I've loaded it up with a bunch of shapefiles.

I'm trying to get the database to do on-the-fly unions of geometries.

Here is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Union(the_geom)) FROM (SELECT geom FROM forecast_zones WHERE 
state = 'ND' AND zone IN ('002','011','021','035','046','050')) as the_geom;
```

The Subquery to pull the geometries of the individual zones works fine:

```
SELECT geom FROM forecast_zones WHERE state = 'ND' AND zone IN 
('002','011','021','035','046','050');
```

But whenever I try to pass that to ST_Union I get undefined function errors.

**EDIT:**

Here is the query I ended up using that works:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Union(forecast_zones.geom)) AS geom FROM forecast_zones
WHERE forecast_zones.state = 'ND' AND forecast_zones.zone IN
('002','011','021','035','046','050')
GROUP BY forecast_zones.state
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a query I use to merge all 'elementary school boundary' features into a single boundary based on their name. this essentially does a dissolve of all chunks of elementary boundaries by their name, and gives me back a table of unioned boundaries. we would do this for middle and high schools too...

```
    select 
elem_name 
, elem_num  
   , st_union(b.geom) as geom
    from boundaries as b
    where b.elem_num > 0
    group by b.elem_name, b.elem_num;
```

- gets the name and number of the elementary school from boundaries
- unions the geometry of the boundaries where the elem_num (school number) is greater than 0
- groups (unions) them by their name and number